# strange behavior of C++ STL container set

Tags: c++, stl, set

I am having some very strange behavior when using a set (it's actual a 3d vector of sets). I have the following at the end of a loop (the comments are behavior the fourth time the loop occurs, so it's not happenining right away)

```
cout<<"size of set at 3 0 0 is "<<particles_celllist.at(3).at(0).at(0).size()<<endl; 
//returns 4

grid_locations[box_counter][0]=i*xgridlength;
cout<<"size of set at 3 0 0 is "<<particles_celllist.at(3).at(0).at(0).size()<<endl; 
//returns 4

grid_locations[box_counter][1]=(i+1)*xgridlength;
cout<<"size of set at 3 0 0 is "<<particles_celllist.at(3).at(0).at(0).size()<<endl; 
//returns 4

grid_locations[box_counter][2]=j*ygridlength;
cout<<"size of set at 3 0 0 is "<<particles_celllist.at(3).at(0).at(0).size()<<endl; 
//returns 4

grid_locations[box_counter][3]=(j+1)*ygridlength;
cout<<"size of set at 3 0 0 is "<<particles_celllist.at(3).at(0).at(0).size()<<endl; 
//returns 4

grid_locations[box_counter][4]=k*zgridlength;
cout<<"size of set at 3 0 0 is "<<particles_celllist.at(3).at(0).at(0).size()<<endl; 
//returns 4

grid_locations[box_counter][5]=(k+1)*zgridlength;
cout<<"size of set at 3 0 0 is "<<particles_celllist.at(3).at(0).at(0).size()<<endl;
// returns 1071644672

grid_rank_lookup[box_counter]=use_rank;
cout<<"size of set at 3 0 0 is "<<particles_celllist.at(3).at(0).at(0).size()<<endl;
// returns 1071644672

box_counter++;
cout<<"size of set at 3 0 0 is "<<particles_celllist.at(3).at(0).at(0).size()<<endl;
// returns 1071644672

use_rank=(use_rank+1)%world.size();
cout<<"size of set at 3 0 0 is "<<particles_celllist.at(3).at(0).at(0).size()<<endl;
// returns 1071644672
```

The definition of `particles_celllist`, `grid_rank_lookup`, and `grid_locations` are:

```
vector<vector<vector<set<int> > > > particles_celllist;
map<int,vector<double> > grid_locations
map<int,int> grid_rank_lookup
```

Note: the first is a local variable, while the other 2 are inputs to the function.

I have no idea what is causing this or even how to go about figuring out what is wrong. I see no logical explanation within the confines of the code itself, so maybe it is something to do with the memory? The comments are what happens when I run it on a single processor, but if I do it on 2 processors (it is an mpi code) it seems to happen at a random time on a random processor (I didn't include all the details here because the code is quite long, but I can post it if you feel the information here is not sufficient to guess at what is wrong)

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that one of your index values is out of bounds, or that you are writing through a dangling pointer somewhere. If you running under Linux, use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).

Comment: Are you sure that `grid_locations[box_counter].size()` is at least 6? You are writing to indexes `0..5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1071644672` has the same value representation as `1.75` (as 32-bit values).

```
grid_locations[box_counter][5]=(k+1)*zgridlength;
```

is overwriting memory belonging to `particles_celllist`.  Probably `grid_locations[box_counter]` is insufficiently large to allow `grid_locations[box_counter][5]` to access memory correctly; try changing it to `grid_locations[box_counter].at(5)` and see if it breaks.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what I get for forgetting to pre-size the vectors (could have sworn I did...). Now everything works.